# Django: How to write a clean method for a field that allows mutiple file uploads?

Tags: python, django, forms, django-forms, form-fields

I have a form for uploading images.

If I follow Django's standard for [cleaning a specific field attribute of a form](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-a-specific-field-attribute), this is what my clean method would typically look like:

```
class UploadImagesForm(forms.Form):
    image = forms.FileField()

    def clean_image(self):
        file = self.cleaned_data['image']
        if file:
            if file._size > 15*1024*1024:
                raise forms.ValidationError("Image file is too large ( > 15mb ).")
            return file
        else:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Could not read the uploaded file.")
```

**However, I'm using a form that allows multiple images to be uploaded at once, all through the same widget (ie, the user can Shift+click to select several files on the file browser)**. So whenever I need to access the files in a view or in a handler, I use something like `request.FILES.getlist('images')` in a for loop. How the hell do I write a clean method for this field?? I'm lost.

Here's what my form looks like.

```
class UploadImagesForm(forms.Form):
    images = forms.FileField(widget=forms.ClearableFileInput(attrs={'multiple': 'multiple'}))
```

I would like the field's clean method to check the file size of *each file submitted*, as illustrated in the first block of code above.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use `self.files.getlist('images')` in `clean` method to iterate over multiple images:

```
def clean_images(self):
    files = self.files.getlist('images')
    for file in files:
        if file:
            if file._size > 15*1024*1024:
                raise forms.ValidationError("Image file is too large ( > 15mb ).")
        else:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Could not read the uploaded file.")
    return files
```