# Validate a field of form that allows multiple photos upload

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a custom form that allows to upload multiple photos which I'm using in **UserAdmin** model. Also I have my own validator for a field in **User** model. I was trying to make a validator for the field of my form by overriding *clean* method, but *clean* method made my custom validator in User model unworkable, so it means my validator for a field in User model became useless because *clean* method in **forms.py** works for everything. I've tried to go through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14392700/django-how-to-write-a-clean-method-for-a-field-that-allows-mutiple-file-uploads) answer but it didn't help me. How can I make each validator work for the field that they are intended for?

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe

from .models import UserImage


class PhotoUploadForm(forms.ModelForm):
    photo = forms.FileField(
        widget=forms.ClearableFileInput(attrs={'multiple': True}),
        required=False,
        help_text='Необходимо количество фото - 10',
        label=mark_safe("<strong style='color:black'>Фото</strong>")
        )

    def clean_photos(self):
        photos = self.files.getlist('photo')
        if len(photos) != 10:
            raise forms.ValidationError(
                {'photo': f'Вы попытались загрузить {len(photos)} фотографий'})
        return photos

    class Meta:
        model = UserImage
        fields = '__all__'
```

**admin.py**

```
@admin.register(User)
class UserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = PhotoUploadForm
```

**models.py**

```
class User(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(
        verbose_name='Имя',
        max_length=40,
        )
    last_name = models.CharField(
        verbose_name='Фамилия',
        max_length=40
        )
    rfid_mark = models.CharField(
        verbose_name='RFID',
        max_length=10,
        unique=True,
        help_text='RFID должен состоять из 10 символов',
        error_messages={
            'unique': 'Такой RFID уже существует'
        },
        validators=[validate_rfid_length]
        )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the field you want to clean is called `photo` then the clean method you need is called `clean_photo()` not `clean_photos()`

Comment: Thank you so much! Didn't pay attention to that